# Maya LT Wax Brush behaving strange, can't fix it

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

The Wax brush is subtracting instead of building, here are the tool settings.

It was working fine last night and now suddenly just wants to invert the brush my itself. Even inverting the mesh is giving me the same subtracting result.

[Wax Brush tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDLvD.png)

[Wax brush subtracting instead of building gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY34q.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following MEL commands in Script Editor when your Wax Brush is active:

```
sculptMeshCacheValues_ResetToolUI "sculptMeshCacheContext";
sculptMeshCacheValues sculptMeshCacheContext;
toolPropertyShow;
dR_updateToolSettings;
```

If it doesn't help, try to reset user preferences:

[Reset your Maya preferences](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-393D1ECA-9B6E-4625-B5B1-3F28E62AFB1C-htm.html)